# May one patch a hole in a Sefer Torah?

Tags: halacha, safrus

Let's say the Torah parchment has a hole such that a letter is missing where the hole is, making the entire Torah "pasul".

May one use either of these methods to fix the problem?

1 - Get a small blank piece of parchment; glue it to the back of the original parchment, and write the missing letter after it has been glued?

2 - Get a piece of parchment, write the letter on the small piece of parchment, then glue that to the large parchment such that the letter appears through the hole in the correct place?

If neither method is allowable, does this mean that the only way is to rewrite the entire *yeri'ah* (parchment sheet)?

**Note:** I am looking for a halachic source. Additionally, you may include information of the practical aspects of why this may or may not be a good solution (from a safrut or preservation view.)

Comment: I believe that the Kesset haSofer assurs this, although I don't remember the siman off the top of my head.

Comment: If I am not mistaken it's called a "matlit" and is allowed, but there are no doubt all sorts of details that need to be considered with which I am not familiar. If this is a real case, a Sofer must be consulted. http://hebrewstam.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/blog-post_5013.html gives more detail with references (in Hebrew)

Comment: Note that if @Epicentre's suggestion of a matlit is in fact halachically doable, it would not be applicable to tefillin and mezuzot, which must be written kesidran (in order) (see SA OC 25 ed seq.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes." The long answer is "see Kesset hasofer siman 7 and chakira 5 for the laws of writing on patches."

Comment: If you can link a source, that helps. If you can summarize an answer to any of the two methods I mentioned above, even better. The bounty may be an incentive for you, but I see that it expires, tomorrow ;-)